# UISlider with different colors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uislider

I have a slider with min value 0 and max value 5(be any value) , i need to display 5 different colors in the same slider ie 0-1 one color, 1-2 another color and so on. Is this possible . Please help me if any idea.

Comment: This might help you :https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=slider

Comment: This can help you a lot Just try it



[][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865528/customizing-a-slider-control


Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 400.0f, 320.0f, 35.0f)];
[slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // Initial color of selection
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[[self view] addSubview:slider];
```

In target method, you can set the colors

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {

/* 

 Here you check the value of slider from [slider value] call;

 then set the color of slider by using

 [slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

 */
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use images for that and in the

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
 // depending on the value 
 // if value is 1 {
    [mySlider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftImageforValue=1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mySlider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightImageforValue=1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place an ImageView with your desired colors under the slider, and set MinTrackTint and MaxTrackTint to ClearColor. Slider will be fully transparent(except the thumb) but functional.